# fread: how to espace separators inline in field values?

Tags: r, csv, escaping, data.table

> *Notice that the R's base command read.csv works such that
>   `read.csv(file=fileName, dec=".", sep=",", header=T)` while `fread` does not work in the following demo, having quoted separators inline. We concentrate now on the data.table and fread, read.csv too slow.*

---

I have a csv file that has comma as a field value separators and dot as a decimal point. The file `MyFile.csv` has field names with commas and dots, such as `"Product.Apple.Green,Purple"` where double quotes try to separate dots and commas. However, the separation with double quotes does not work with the fread such that

```
Sys.setlocale('LC_NUMERIC', 'fi_FI.UTF-8')   
fread(file="MyFile.csv", sep=",", dec=".")
```

so for example the fields

```
`CustomerID, ProductID, Prod.Sub, "Prod.Sub,feature", A.B.C, "A,B,C,D"`
```

is read, with dash `-` denoting field separation now, as

```
`CustomerID - ProductID - Prod.Sub - "Prod.Sub - feature" - A.B.C - "A - B - C - D"`
```

where `"Prod.Sub, feature"` is wrongly read as two fields `"Prod.Sub - feature"` and `"A,B,C,D"` is wrongly read as `"A - B - C - D"`.

**How can I inline escape separators with data.table's fread?**

Comment: Which version of `data.table` are you using? When I use `fread('myfile.csv')`, the data is read normally in the latest version (I made a csv-file with the field names you described). Maybe you can include the first line of the csv-file?

Comment: Can't replicate on v1.9.6. `fread` works as expected on `dt= fread(
  'CustomerID, ProductID, Prod.Sub, "Prod.Sub,feature", A.B.C, "A,B,C,D"
  1,2,3,4,5,6' )` (note there is a new line between the header and data - doesn't show in comments)

Comment: @Jaap data.table is 1.10.0 version. R's sessionInfo() data [here](http://pastie.org/private/wg0piep3ghyz6k76egm7oq) and locale is `C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C`, could that be a problem if fread uses the location parameters for the separators?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with v1.10.0. Could you include the steps to reproduce this problem in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool thing about `fread`, it can use system commands (at least on Unix).

So make use of `sed`, for example:

```
fread("sed 's/,\ /| /g' MyFile.csv", sep = "|", dec = ".")
```

Replace `|` with any separator that might not conflict.

Note: In your text example, the delimiter is shown as `,` +  (space). Without space the solution does not work!

Also: without space (only `,`), the quoted fields get processed by `fread` correctly using `data.table` version 1.10.0